# iOS Application Crash Report, Cannot find what value is nil for which "key"

Tags: ios, objective-c, appstore-approval, crash-reports

I just received these reports from Apple but I can't figure out which property on my ViewController is missing or not hooked up properly in the IB. The fact that I have checked both of them throughly and I get no warnings when compiling the project leaves me with no other option then to re write everything.

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x182b92950 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x18f56c1fc objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x182b925d4 -[NSException raise] + 12
3   Foundation                      0x183650720 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 256
4   CoreFoundation                  0x182ade09c -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 248
5   UIKit                           0x185f16dd0 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1232
6   UIKit                           0x185e5b878 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
7   UIKit                           0x185b5c488 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 88
8   UIKit                           0x185b5c3f4 -[UIViewController view] + 32
9   UIKit                           0x185d09868 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 704
10  UIKit                           0x185c13f54 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 464
11  UIKit                           0x185c13d24 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 56
12  UIKit                           0x185c13ca4 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 200
13  UIKit                           0x185b56ff8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 348
14  QuartzCore                      0x185748258 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184
15  QuartzCore                      0x185742e20 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 300
16  QuartzCore                      0x185742cd8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
17  QuartzCore                      0x185742560 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 280
18  QuartzCore                      0x185742304 CA::Transaction::commit() + 424
19  QuartzCore                      0x18573bc38 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
20  CoreFoundation                  0x182b530a8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
21  CoreFoundation                  0x182b50330 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
22  CoreFoundation                  0x182b506bc __CFRunLoopRun + 764
23  CoreFoundation                  0x182a916d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
24  GraphicsServices                0x18872dc0c GSEventRunModal + 168
25  UIKit                           0x185bc2fdc UIApplicationMain + 1156
26  AppName                     0x10012e1f4 main (main.m:22)
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x18fb5faa0 start + 4
```

Comment: Are you using storyboard or nibs? In either case, just go through all the nib/storyboard files, click on each view controller (make sure it is the view controller that is highlighted and NOT the view on the left pane), click the connection properties tab on the right side of Xcode, and see if any of the connected outlets have an exclamation mark (indicating that there is nothing in code that outlet is connected to). Click the X to remove.

Comment: Im using Nibs. Also, I checked it a lot of times, the weird thing is that it works for me on all devices but for Apple's approval team it doesn't.

Comment: and you've checked every view controller in your app when running the app on the device? Never receive a crash?

Comment: Do you set any user info in any of your view controllers via the nib itself? Are any of these properties invalid? I am thinking it is this and not an outlet issue now because your stack trace does not show `-[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect]` which would appear in an outlet error.

Comment: @rvijay007 yep, i did. Never a crash while testing myself. But the last bit that you pointed out is worth exploring since I have UIButton subclass that takes a User Defined Runtime Attribute called Heading. But if I go this route, all my labels and textfields and Buttons are done the same way and they seem to work fine.

Comment: I guess this is not very useful, but just in case. I had an error in the code that was only apparent in the simulator. You probably have run the app in the simulator recently; if you haven't, try that (maybe it helps, maybe it just doesn't give you further info). Also: What are the differences between their execution and yours? Are there any (e.g. they tested it on an iPad while you test in on iPhone)?